# How to Align three views horizontally with intermediate views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

I want to align 3 layouts vertically so that each of the three text views come exactly one below other. It has got intermediate views. 
So I cannot use the property layout_below using relative layout. While I have managed to align the above two layouts with linear layout and weights, the third one consists of an image view and the image view is going at the center.
   Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="@string/status_heading"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"


            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:src="@drawable/my_drawable" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="test"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

When there are 3 text views it works fine, but this image view is somehow going to the center of itself and not aligning properly.
 Thank you :)

Comment: you need that image should occupy whole imgaview area?

Comment: Please use gravity as "center" into LinearLayout.

Comment: No ,its a small image and I need it somewhere near the start. I can use padding but that is not a generalized solution. @Suraj

Comment: @SaurabhVadhva yes I already did but of no use

Comment: @Pritish can u share your expected output as image?

Comment: @NileshRathod I wish I could,but its an official screen shot, so I cannot . But its like 3 text views horizontally and vertically like an 3 * 3 matrices . Only thing is last row will have one image view in the centre

Comment: @Pritish just take the screenshot of that particular row so that we can understand what you want exactly.

Comment: @Pritish your code works fine as it is, but it seems you did not post all the attributes of the ImageView

Comment: @Pritish help us to help you with out expected output we can only guess

Comment: @Pritish try using `android:scaleType="fitStart"`
as you said that you need image to start.

Comment: *but this image view is somehow going to the center of itself and not aligning properly* what do you mean?

Comment: @mTak like textviews are responding to gravity : start by positioning itself to start , image view is still going at centre

Comment: @Suraj fitStart worked perfectly , thanks

Comment: @NileshRathod will try it out as well, but as of now solution by suraj is working.

Comment: @Pritish ok no problem

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the `Image` with any other `Layout`, so that it will no go to center but appear at the start:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="@string/status_heading"
        android:textSize="11sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/my_drawable" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="test"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum=".9">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="@string/status_heading"
        android:textSize="11sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="test"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can alter the weight and weightSum according to your design

Answer (score 0):

Height of text views is wrap content so there size will be dependent on text size which is different in your case. Now height of image is defined in your case so obviously it will not be aligned.

What you can do is give height to parent view and layout gravity as center.

Something like this -

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:src="@drawable/d"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="test"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

You can add gravity to center for text views for proper horizontal space.